# RD Gateway Manager cannot connect to local server

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop-gateway

I am logged in onto this Windows 2012 R2 VM with Remote Desktop, I launched the Remote Desktop Gateway Manager, I right-clicked on the RD Gateway Manager node in the left tree, I selected Connect to RD Gateway Server, I left the Local server selection and I clicked OK. I get the following message:

"The RD Gateway Manager snap-in console cannot connect to the server "SERVER" because it is not a RD Gateway server."

Any ideas on what might cause this? Does a running anti-virus have any effect? There is no error event log.

As a side note, the real reason I want to get to this dialog is to turn off the inactivity session timeout which kills my session after I leave work. But that's another issue. Changing the local policy didn't work - the VM belongs to a domain. I am curious about this for now.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Lets check several things.

- Make sure that the RD Gateway role is installed on your RDS server. To do this open your `Server Manager > Remote Desktop Services` (left tree) and in the `Deployment Servers` section, make sure you have the RD Gateway role installed and setup under `Deployment Overview` OR go through `Manage > Remove Roles and Features` and see if the RD Gateway role is checked. If it is not or you have trouble getting to this area, install/reinstall your RDS Services.
- Open `Services` and make sure `Remote Desktop Gateway` is running. If not, try to start it.
- Still in `Services`, make sure `Windows Internal Database` is running. If not, try to start it.
- Still in `Services`, make sure `Remote Desktop Management` is running, if not, try to start it.

If you have any issues with starting the Services mentioned, check Event Viewer under `Windows Logs > System` and post any errors that you get related to these services.

**Reinstall/Install**

Open Server Manager > Manage > Add Roles and Features. Click on `Next`on `Before you Begin` > Check `Remote Desktop Services Installation` and Next > Select your Server under `RD Connection Broker` and leave `Standard deployment` checked, Next > Select the type of session you want to use (VM or Session) - Session: Remote users connect to the RDS server directly; VM: Remote users connect to a Virtual Machine isolating the users from the server in case the server has sensitive data. I'm going to use Session for this example... - `Review Roles and Services`, Next > `Specify RD Connection Broker server` and add your RDS server to the Pool, Next > `Specify RD Web Access server` and add your RDS server to the Pool and Check `Install the RD Web Access role on the RD Connection Broker server`, Next > `Specify RD Session Host server` and add your RDS server to the Pool, Next > `Confirm Selections`, if everything looks good then proceed installing. Check `Restart the destination server automatically if required` if you want to or restart your server yourself. If you need a visual guide, you can take a look [here](https://msfreaks.wordpress.com/2013/12/09/windows-2012-r2-remote-desktop-services-part-1/).

Once the roles are done installing, open Server Manager once more and go back to `Remote Desktop Services` in the left tree. If everything loads right, you can continue configuring your RD Gateway which is pretty straight forward. Now you can check back into RD Gateway Manager and see if you can connect.

Hope this helps and let us know if you run into more issues!

Comment: I previously installed the Remote Desktop Services but I haven't been able to remote desktop anymore, so I uninstalled them remotely using powershell, then I was able to RD again. Does it make sense?